# Alternative to Amazon S3 for the data center?

Tags: content-management-system, jakarta-ee, amazon-s3, cdn

I'm looking to for a service that is similar to Amazon S3, a simple service to store and retrieve arbitrary data (and meta-data), but one that runs locally in your own data center.  Strictly speaking, I'm not sure whether you would call this a CDN or a lightweight CMS.

It must be horizontally scalable (both for storage and bandwidth) and fault tolerable.  It must also support REST, preferably WS too, with a pluggable authentication and authorization system.  Something built with Java EE would be preferable for more convenient integration and extensibility, but this is just a personal preference, and it not a requirement.

Suggestions?

Comment: If it's inside your data centre, why not just use some sort of SAN?

Comment: The SAN is just the storage part (isn't it?).  I'm looking for the storage and the APIs to go along with it: to store and retrieve arbitrary data and meta-data, security, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a few open source solutions I have come across that deserve further research:

1. [Apache Sling](http://incubator.apache.org/sling/site/index.html) (JCR based CMS ([JSR170](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170), [JSR283](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283)), RESTful interface).
2. [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) (Java based distributed data-store, map reduce functionality).
3. [HBase](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase) (built on top of Hadoop, provding Google Bigtable-like capabilities).
4. [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (Erlang based key/value DB with Map/Reduce functionality, RESTful interface).
5. [Dynomite](http://github.com/cliffmoon/dynomite/tree/master) (Erlang based, Amazon [dynamo](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) clone).
6. [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) (Distributed key-value storage system).
7. [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra) (highly scalable, eventually consistent, distributed, structured key-value store).
8. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (highly scalable, JSON document based storage).

Answer (score 6):

Walrus project (mostly s3 api compatible) . . .

http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusStorage_v1.4

Answer (score 2):

[Park place](http://github.com/why/parkplace/tree/master) is an S3 clone in Ruby.

Comment: I was trying to find the url for that one.

Comment: This looks interesting.  Is there really no drop-in JEE solution in this space?  There has to be (not that I have anything against Ruby , in fact, I'll likely spike park place).  Perhaps I'm just missing the correct classification and terminology for these types of solutions, so they don't turn up in my searching?

Comment: There might be but I don't know of one. I just know about this one because a dead tree book I'm reading mentioned it

Answer (score -6):

In addition to Park Place, the only other big player against S3 right now is Nirvanix.
[Nirvanix](http://www.nirvanix.com/)